# Using local SRID in datawarehouse

Tags: coordinate-system

I was looking for a data warehouse solution that supports my local spatial reference system (EPSG:28992). I searched trough Google, Microsoft, Snowflake and Amazon documentation and found out that almost all data warehouse solutions only support WGS84.

It seems that [redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/geospatial-overview.html) support multiple SRS.

Does redshift support [EPSG:28992](https://epsg.io/28992)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: @IanTurton Hi, sorry that my question does not follow the rules. Just so I can fix this. My question is "Can Product A do action A". English is not my main language, but that is a factual question right? And if product A can't do action A, is there a product that can. Am I not allowed to ask this? It irritates me a little that my question is just slaughtered. Is it that bad?

Comment: Your question was not "slaughtered" or "burned" it was closed to allow you to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this page in the RedShift docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/spatial-copy-shapefile.html) gives this:

> If a projection description file (.prj) exists with the shapefile, Redshift uses it to determine the spatial reference system id (SRID). If the SRID is valid, the resulting geometry has this SRID assigned. If the SRID value associated with the input geometry does not exist, the resulting geometry has the SRID value zero.

So it sounds like you should be fine